# Django isn't authenticating user already logged in through web app frontend using keycloak

Tags: django, keycloak, openid-connect

I am building an application that uses django as a backend for data processing and management calls served to a Vue3 SPA. I am using Keycloak for authentication and using keycloak-js and mozilla-django-oidc to handle authentication for each.

Each work separately fine, I can navigate to the django app, login and see the data behind protected views (and get redirected properly if I a not logged in). Likewise I can login to the frontend and get a token and associated data. I can even login to the django app, then navigate to the frontend and calls are made with the correct session information and it all works fine.

The challenge is when I just login to the frontend and make a call to the django app it doesn't recognize it as being an authenticated user request - I am guessing it has something to do with not creating a django session, but am honestly a bit lost at this point.

Is there a way to ingest the token information and have django authenticate the user and start a session when the call is made from the frontend?

Comment: Any breakthrough with this?